# PHP cron job to POST login info daily?

Tags: php, post, cron

This may be a silly reason to be asking this question. Where I work, we have a contest we are doing for fun and it involves earning points on a website. One way to earn a point daily is simply by logging in. It got me wondering if there were a way to write a PHP script that would POST my login information on a daily basis, and if so, what would be the general steps to do something like this. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library to send HTTP-query to your server and then schedule script with that in [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Simple.